# PHP app running in Docker only uploading certain files

Tags: php, docker

As the title suggests, Docker, running PHP 7.3-fpm is only uploading some files. This is what I've found.

I have an application that allows users to select a file and upload to Slim PHP (I'm using Postman to test).

**My docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
php:
    container_name: app-backend
    image: php:7.3-fpm
    env_file:
        - ./backend/.env
    working_dir: /var/www/backend
    command: php -S 0.0.0.0:3000 -t public
    environment:
        docker: "true"
    ports:
        - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www
        - ./backend/config/custom.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
    networks:
        - app-network
```

**For completeness, my Dockerfile (ignore the Python stuff as I need that and don't want to run another container yet)**

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm
WORKDIR /application

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install apt-utils libxml2-dev gnupg apt-transport-https \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install git \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

COPY src /var/www/backend/uploads
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/backend/uploads

RUN docker-php-ext-install intl mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libzip-dev zlib1g-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN apt-get install -y vim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install pandas 
RUN pip3 install numpy 
RUN pip3 install statsmodels 
RUN pip3 install pickle4 
RUN pip3 install json2 
RUN pip3 install matplotlib
RUN apt update && apt install -y libsm6 libxext6
RUN apt-get install -y libxrender-dev
RUN apt-get update
ENV VERSION 8
ENV UPDATE 91
ENV BUILD 14
EXPOSE 3000
```

So the thing I've noticed is that if I select any file that I've created in VSCode inside the project folder regardless of the extension, the upload works fine.

If I create a file in VSCode and then move that file anywhere on my machine (Mac - Big Sur), it uploads fine regardless of the extension.

If I select any other file in any other location, with extension, the upload fails with no errors. I suspect it's a permission thing however I chmod the files, chown the files, manually changed the permission in the "info" inspector to god mode. Nothing works.

So a couple of things, absolutely open to improving my docker image (I'm fairly new to this whole containerisation thing) and 2, any ideas why any other file not created in VSCode inside the project directory won't upload?

**And PHP**

```
$app->post('/', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
    $directory = $this->get('upload_directory');

    $uploadedFiles = $request->getUploadedFiles();

    // handle single input with single file upload
    $uploadedFile = $uploadedFiles['filename'];
    if ($uploadedFile->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $filename = moveUploadedFile($directory, $uploadedFile);
        $response->write('uploaded ' . $filename . '<br/>');
    }
});

/**
 * Moves the uploaded file to the upload directory and assigns it a unique name
 * to avoid overwriting an existing uploaded file.
 *
 * @param string $directory directory to which the file is moved
 * @param UploadedFile $uploadedFile file uploaded file to move
 * @return string filename of moved file
 */
function moveUploadedFile($directory, UploadedFile $uploadedFile)
{
    $extension = pathinfo($uploadedFile->getClientFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $basename = bin2hex(random_bytes(8)); // see http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php
    $filename = sprintf('%s.%0.8s', $basename, $extension);

    $uploadedFile->moveTo($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);

    return $filename;
}
```

Comment: It would probably help more to show your PHP code rather than your docker files.

Comment: PHP portion added.